# Django Many-to-Many Relationship Permutation Relationships

Tags: django, django-models

I have a self-referencing Many-to-Many Relationship like so:

```
class User(models.Model):
    groups = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, null=True)
```

When I create a relationship between User 1 and User 2, this is bidirectional. I can see this with:

```
User_1_obj.groups.all()
User_2_obj.groups.all()
```

However, when I add a User 3 into the relationships using:

```
User_1_obj.groups.add(User_3_obj)
```

User 1 and User 3 are linked bidirectionally. But I also want User 2 and User 3 (and any other Users in the relationships to be linked). In other words, I want all permutations to be linked to each other, where:

```
User 1 linked to User 2, User 3, User 4
User 2 linked to User 1, User 3, User 4
User 3 linked to User 1, User 2, User 4
User 4 linked to User 1, User 2, User 3
```

Is there a simpler way to do this than iterating through all the links and add connectinos that are missing?

Thanks! All help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to do it in this way? What is wrong with creating a `Group` model that User instances could be be reference?

Comment: Hey Marcus, thanks for replying. Not sure I understand how I would set up a Group model and cover all permutation links between Users? I'd appreciate it if you could clarify

Comment: Are you trying to add the new User to all the existing User?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using a self-referential relationship in the wrong situation.  Self-referential relationships are useful if you're trying to an arbitrary undirected graph of connections between users.

If being connected to a user means you're automatically connected to all other users, and all of those connections are totally equivalent semantically, then it seems to me that you're trying to define something more like a graph with [complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) [connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29).  If this is the case, then each user can really only belong to one group.

You *could* do this with your scheme, but as you can see, it's going to require a lot of manual management enforce your fully connected condition, overly descriptive.  A step in a better direction would be to this by making grouping a simple field, like a nullable IntegerField.

```
class User(models.Model):
    group = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

Then you could query for all users in the same group as a given `myUser` just by `User.objects.filter(group=myUser.group)`. The only tricky part would be that you would have to reassign groups for a bunch of user at once if two users in previously unconnected groups become connected.  But you can just do a [bulk update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once) to reassign all users in the second group to the first one, to merge the groups.

One question you need to ask yourself though is whether a user disconnecting from any other user in the same group results in that user disconnecting from all users in the group.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to **get all other users**, excluding the instance your already have, then this would do the trick:

```
class User(models.Model):
    def groups(self):
        return User.objects.exclude(pk=self.pk)
```

However, if you only want to search a subset of `User` instances you could create a second model called `Group`. (This all seems a little patronising, since we are now essentially replicating `django.contib.auth.models`.)

```
class Group(models.Model):
    # Some attributes you would like (maybe a name, or code)

class User(models.Model):
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, related_name='users')

    def get_linked_users(self, group):
        return group.users.exclude(pk=self.pk)
```

What you're trying to achieve is too vaguely defined, but these are a couple of ways to represent relationships between instances in Django.

---

I'm not sure, however, that permutations should to be represented in a database. I would just get retrive all the `User` objects I wished to include, and work out the permutations after the fact with Python.

Maybe you could go into more detail regarding the reason behind this attempt. Maybe there is a more simple way.